# How to create a new admin user in Portainer at the shell?

Tags: docker

I've newly joined a team having root access to a Linux based Docker host with Portainer up and running on it. That whole setup was implemented by someone not available to the company anymore and people lack docs. So as of now, we are not able to login into Portainer because of a lacke of credentials for any Portainer user, even the admin one created during installation.

I know how to [reset that admin password](https://docs.portainer.io/advanced/reset-admin) at the shell, its properly documented. But I would like to avoid that, because someone in the company might still have that admin password and we might only not know whom to ask and stuff. As we have root access to the Linux itself, I thought it would be easy to simply add another user in Portainer at the shell, not breaking too much for anyone else I don't know yet. But I can't find any instructions on doing so.

**So, can new admin users be created at the shell for Portainer and if so, how? :-)**

Thanks!

Comment: How? ASK the IT Dep to reset the main and afterwards, create a user imho.

Comment: Reset the password, document it in your common password safe where you store all your passwords. If anyone else needs it they can look it up.